# How close should be the boundary value of $x$ and $y$ to ensure that $|x(t)-y(t)|<0.1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the following differential equation:

$$y' = \sin y\cdot \sin t+y\cos t$$

Say that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ solve this equation, and that $x(t_0) = x_0$ , $y(t_0)=y_0$.

Find $\varepsilon$ small enough such that if $|x_0-y_0| < \varepsilon$ then $|x(t)-y(t)|<0.1$ for all $t \in [0,10]$

I tried to solve it using Gronwall's lemma, but couldn't find such an $\varepsilon$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$ \left|\dfrac{d}{dt} (x-y)\right| = |(\sin(x) - \sin(y)) \sin(t) + (x - y) \cos(t)| \le |x - y| (|\sin(t)| + |\cos(t)|)$$